# docker on windows 10 - mariadb fails to start

Tags: windows, docker, mariadb

Using Docker Desktop v2.1.0.4 on Windows 10

I have experimental features turned on in Settings.

I am trying to run the command given by mariadb dockerhub `docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:latest` from https://hub.docker.com/_/mariadb

```
2019-11-14 18:34:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Database files initialized
2019-11-14 18:34:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Starting temporary server
2019-11-14 18:34:56+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Waiting for server startup
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic) starting as process 126 ...
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.11
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE2 crc32 instructions
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] mysqld: O_TMPFILE is not supported on /tmp (disabling future attempts)
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 256M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: 128 out of 128 rollback segments are active.
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
2019-11-14 18:34:56 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: 10.4.10 started; log sequence number 139827; transaction id 21
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 191114 18:34:57
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@b78a8d99a45b' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Warning] 'user' entry '@b78a8d99a45b' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@% root@b78a8d99a45b' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] Reading of all Master_info entries succeeded
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] Added new Master_info '' to hash table
2019-11-14 18:34:57 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
Version: '10.4.10-MariaDB-1:10.4.10+maria~bionic'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  mariadb.org binary distribution
2019-11-14 18:34:57+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Temporary server started.
2019-11-14 18:34:58 9 [ERROR] InnoDB: Cannot rename './mysql/time_zone.ibd' to './mysql/#sql-ib20.ibd' because the source file does not exist.
ERROR 1030 (HY000) at line 10: Got error 194 "Tablespace is missing for a table" from storage engine InnoDB
```

I tried 10.1, 10.2, 10.3 tags, same thing although 10.1 is slightly different error. I tried adding lower_case_table_names = 1 option via `docker run --name some-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=my-secret-pw -d mariadb:latest --lower_case_table_names=1` still same problem.

I've googled a lot, and all searches result in someone having this error on startup

```
2016-10-18 13:14:06 140161674901440 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
2016-10-18 13:14:06 140161674901440 [ERROR] Aborting
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi, it seems that the problem is the InnoDb since in your log-file it prints that "mysqld: ready for connections.", but fail when the InnoDb wants to rename the time_zone. What happen when you try to set the time-zone as described here https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/320 ?

Comment: That's a good point about innoDb, I tried setting the TZ env variable and have same problem. Thank you for the help though. I think I found the problem and that is on Docker for Windows I can only run Windows containers or Linux (I must switch to Linux in settings.) But I'm trying to run a legacy asp.net container with a mariadb database on my local machine but that's a different issue.

Comment: I've tried deleting all downloaded images and using a `--platform linux` (while still on Windows Containers) when I issue the run command. However still the same issue. I was following https://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2019/06/12/windows-and-linux-docker-containers-side-by-side/ which shows examples of ubuntu working, so I believe it may be specific to mariadb

Comment: I used a mariaDb a a few days ago without any Problems. I Run it as docker-compose file i am not sure if this hast any impact

Comment: I get the same issue, and are also running on Win10 with experimental on. Did you ever find a solution? Containerise it, run anywhere.....hmmm

Comment: My problem was that I was trying to run mariadb while in "Windows Containers" mode, you have to switch to "Linux Containers". But that means I couldn't run an iis container alongside a mariadb container